Does there exist a 5-connected planar graph that is perfect?
I asked this question on math stack, but didn't get any response, so I ask it here.
In a previous post, I proved that no 5-connected maximal planar graph is perfect. (A perfect graph is a graph $G$ such that for every induced subgraph of $G$, the clique number equals the chromatic number）
Naturally, I wanted to ask whether there exists a 5-connected planar graph that is perfect. In some computer searches, I couldn't even find a planar perfect graph with  minimum degree 5.  I have no sufficient reason to show the non-existence, but I also can't think of a construction.

Regarding maximal planar graphs of minimum degree 5, they can all be made using three operations starting at the icosahedron.  See below Fig 7 at https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/plantri-full.pdf .  Now try to prove that if there is an odd hole before an operation, there is one afterwards too. I didn't attempt it.
